# List: How to add constant classes

Tags: c#

I am trying to add velocities to a list but i did not realize by doing this the variable in the list will change when i want them as constants. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks a lot.

My Code

```
    void CalculateVelocity(List<velocity> ListOfVelocity, particle newprojectile, Environment newEnvironment)
    {
        //load in stats
        newEnvironment.gravity = -9.8;
        newprojectile.TimeOfFlight = Convert.ToDouble(txtbox_TimeOfFlight.Text);
        newprojectile.InitialVelocity.Magnitude = Convert.ToDouble(txtbox_InitialVelocity.Text);
        newprojectile.InitialVelocity.AngleOfTravel = Convert.ToDouble(txtb_AngleOLaunch.Text);
        double TimeInterval;
        double FlightTime =0;
        double InitialHVelocity;
        velocity newVelocity;
        newVelocity = new velocity();
        newVelocity.Magnitude = Convert.ToDouble(txtbox_InitialVelocity.Text);
        newVelocity.AngleOfTravel = Convert.ToDouble(txtb_AngleOLaunch.Text);
        newVelocity.AngleOfTravel = newprojectile.InitialVelocity.AngleOfTravel;
        velocity.CalculateVComponent(newVelocity);
        velocity.CalculateHComponent(newVelocity);
        InitialHVelocity = newVelocity.HorizontalVelocity;
        ListOfVelocity.Add(newVelocity);
        if (newprojectile.TimeOfFlight > 60)
        {
            TimeInterval = newprojectile.TimeOfFlight / 60;
        }
        else
        {
            TimeInterval = 1;
        }
        FlightTime =FlightTime+ TimeInterval;
        while (!(newprojectile.TimeOfFlight < FlightTime))
        {
            velocity.CalculateVComponent(newVelocity, FlightTime, newEnvironment, newVelocity.VerticleVelocity);
            ListOfVelocity.Add(newVelocity);
            FlightTime = FlightTime + TimeInterval;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good question, but please provide a [*minimal* code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the `ICloneable` interface in your class `Velocity`:

```
class velocity() : ICloneable
{
    #region ICloneable Members

    public object Clone()
    {
        newVelocity = new Velocity();

        newVelocity .Magnitude = this.Magnitude;
        // ...

        return newVelocity ;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then clone the object in your code:

```
    void CalculateVelocity(List<velocity> ListOfVelocity, particle newprojectile, Environment newEnvironment)
    {
        //load in stats
        newEnvironment.gravity = -9.8;
        newprojectile.TimeOfFlight = Convert.ToDouble(txtbox_TimeOfFlight.Text);
        newprojectile.InitialVelocity.Magnitude = Convert.ToDouble(txtbox_InitialVelocity.Text);
        newprojectile.InitialVelocity.AngleOfTravel = Convert.ToDouble(txtb_AngleOLaunch.Text);
        double TimeInterval;
        double FlightTime =0;
        double InitialHVelocity;
        velocity newVelocity;
        newVelocity = new velocity();
        newVelocity.Magnitude = Convert.ToDouble(txtbox_InitialVelocity.Text);
        newVelocity.AngleOfTravel = Convert.ToDouble(txtb_AngleOLaunch.Text);
        newVelocity.AngleOfTravel = newprojectile.InitialVelocity.AngleOfTravel;
        velocity.CalculateVComponent(newVelocity);
        velocity.CalculateHComponent(newVelocity);
        InitialHVelocity = newVelocity.HorizontalVelocity;
        ListOfVelocity.Add(newVelocity);
        if (newprojectile.TimeOfFlight > 60)
        {
            TimeInterval = newprojectile.TimeOfFlight / 60;
        }
        else
        {
            TimeInterval = 1;
        }
        FlightTime =FlightTime+ TimeInterval;
        while (!(newprojectile.TimeOfFlight < FlightTime))
        {
            newVelocity = (velocity)newVelocity.clone(); // HERE!
            velocity.CalculateVComponent(newVelocity, FlightTime, newEnvironment, newVelocity.VerticleVelocity);
            ListOfVelocity.Add(newVelocity);
            FlightTime = FlightTime + TimeInterval;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh! You're the first to tell me that! :D